# Ant script not compilig spring class files in war file

Tags: java, ant

I am generating an ear file using Ant Script. I see that script perfectly compiles the java class files but when I check the class files in the generated war file they are showing errors as below due to which I am not able to deploy ear to server

```
 public TransportationController()
{
    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tThe import org.springframework cannot be re" +"solved\n\tThe import org.springframework cannot be resolved\n\tThe import org.sp" +"ringframework cannot be resolved\n\tThe import org.springframework cannot be res" +"olved\n\tThe import org.springframework cannot be resolved\n\tThe import org.spr" +"ingframework cannot be resolved\n\tThe import org.springframework cannot be reso" +"lved\n\tThe import com.pepsico.us.sc.updateprocessflagob cannot be resolved\n\tC" 
);
}
```

My Ant script to generate war is as below:

```
 <target name="do.package" depends="common.do.package">
 <war webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml"
  warfile="${output.dir}/sn-ecr-web.war"
  manifest="WebContent/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
 <zipfileset dir="WebContent"/>
 <zipfileset dir="${output.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" prefix="WEB-INF/lib"/>
 </war>
 <delete dir="${output.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
 </target>
```

Comment: Where does the source code of that class come from?  Did you create it?  Did your build create it and put it in the WAR file?  Did it get generated in / by the web container?  Did you decompile something to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the class files in the generated war"? The code snippet you're presented here doesn't compile anything, only creates a war file. What is TransportationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have used the Eclipse compiler to compile your own classes, and that some classes didn't compile (due to missing Spring jars in the compilation classpath). Eclipse generates class files for non-compiling class files, but with methods throwing errors instead of containing the actual code (since it doesn't compile).

Fix the compilation issues, and regenerate your jars.

Comment: Hi, I am not using eclipse[I don't want to] for compiling class files i am running Ant script in the command prompt.Below is the ant script file used :

Comment: AFAIK, javac doesn't create such class files. It simply fails without generating them. Is the failing class one of the classes that your script compiles? Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes the failing class is the one of the class the script compiles.One more thing i want to mention is that when ever the script compiles the src code ,it compiles with out any errors[i see this by looking into the compiled class file],but when the war file is generated then the above problems are displayed in class file.

Comment: Well, if the class file doesn't contain this byte-code on the file system (after compilation), but contains it in the war file, it means that you're not putting the compiled classes in the war file, but other ones.

Comment: Hi,Yes i was by mistake pointing different class files.          Thanks